# Can moving folders/files in github cause a problem?

Tags: github

My github repository is: https://github.com/zorlakov/moviesAndShows
In order to get to the react files and folders (src, public etc) you first have to open the movies-and-shows folder. I was thinking to copy all the content from that folder into the parent folder, and then delete that folder and push to github. Could this create a problem?

Answer (score 2):

This should not be a problem for Github, or even Git.

However, if you want to keep history and ensure that Git is able to detect move/renames, you should work by steps:

```
git mv moves-and-shows/public .
git mv moves-and-shows/src .
git commit -m 'move public and src to root'
```

For the other files, it should also work.

I do expect that you will also have to fix hard coded path (replace `moves-and-shows/public` by `public` and so on).